# Is there a debugging feature in any IDE that lets you see what "path" your code took?

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-2.7, debugging, ide

So I'm debugging a huge piece of code, and it's a huge task. The code involves many conditional (if/else) statements, and to make this debugging job easier, I would like to see what "path" the interpreter took through all the if/elses.

For example:

```
if stuff:
    x = "stuff"
elif otherstuff:
    x = "otherstuff"
else:
    x = "evenmorestuff"
return x
```

My actual code is much more complex than this, and putting `return`s instead of the `x`s isn't an option. But I hope you get the idea.

I would like to see what "path" through the ifs, elifs and elses my code takes when it crashes. For example:

```
|  if stuff:
>      x = "stuff"            (ran this line)
 |     if morestuff:
 |         y = "morestuff"    (skipped this line)
 |     else:
 >         y = "nostuff"      (ran this line)
  |elif otherstuff:
  |    x = "otherstuff"       (skipped this line)
  |else:
  |    x = "evenmorestuff"    (skipped this line)
  >return x                   (ran this line)
```

Is there any feature, in any IDE, that could do this? (I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 with PTVS and Python, so if there's a solution for that, that would be great as I wouldn't have to switch IDEs.) I just have no idea what it would be called, and a google search yielded no results when I searched something similar to this title, so I decided to ask here.

Thanks :)

Comment: er... bump? :P (does that work? lol)

Comment: single stepping lolol

Comment: @towerofnix I've tried single stepping, but the problem is my code is so huge that I have to click the step button over and over again - I'd rather not.

Comment: make a python script to click the button for you, you leet hax0r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb you're looking for is "tracing".

Python has a `trace` module which can do this. I found articles on 
[tracing in general](https://pymotw.com/2/sys/tracing.html) and [the module itself](https://pymotw.com/2/trace/) which look useful.

> The trace module helps you understand the way your program runs. You can trace the statements executed, produce coverage reports, and investigate the relationships between functions that call each other.

You might find that refactoring the code into smaller functions makes it easier to comprehend and/or trace its execution.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I think this is exactly what I needed.